# Get Tables Name Through Plsql Query

Tags: sql, database, oracle, plsql, oracle11g

I need a procedure that input user_name and password then get to me the exist tables in that schema with the create script for each table?

This is what I tried, but is wrong:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE procedure TABLE_INFO(P_USER_NAME IN VARCHAR2,P_PASSWORD IN VARCHAR,P_TABLE_NAME OUT VARCHAR2,P_SCRIPT OUT VARCHAR2) 
IS 
  chk_username all_users.username%type; 
  CURSOR C IS SELECT table_name FROM USER_TABLES; 
  t_tablename user_tables.table_name%type; 
BEGIN 
  SELECT username into chk_username from all_users 
  where chk_username=p_user_name; 
  open c; 
  loop 
    fetch c into t_tablename; 
    exit when c% notfound; 
    end loop; 
exception when no_data_found then 
  dbms_output.put_line('Wrong Username Or Password'); 
  close c; 
end; 
/
```

Comment: you should provide at least your code you already tried and the error your getting

Comment: here is my code which is totally wrong

CREATE OR REPLACE procedure TABLE_INFO(P_USER_NAME IN VARCHAR2,P_PASSWORD IN VARCHAR,P_TABLE_NAME OUT VARCHAR2,P_SCRIPT OUT VARCHAR2)
IS
chk_username all_users.username%type;
CURSOR C IS SELECT table_name FROM USER_TABLES;
t_tablename user_tables.table_name%type;
BEGIN
SELECT username into chk_username from all_users where chk_username=p_user_name;
open c;
loop
fetch c into t_tablename;
exit when c% notfound;
end loop;
exception
when no_data_found then
dbms_output.put_line('Wrong Username Or Password');
close c;
end;
/

Comment: please see how I edited your post and try to edit it yourself further to ask a good question. Also provide the error messages you encounter

Answer (score 0):

```
    Try this code. Let me know if this helps.

    CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE TABLE_INFO(
        P_USER_NAME IN VARCHAR2,
        --    P_PASSWORD  IN VARCHAR, --Not required
        P_TABLE_NAME OUT sys_refcursor)
      --    P_SCRIPT OUT VARCHAR2) --Not required
    AS
    BEGIN

    -----------------------For DDL script use dbms_metadata.get_ddl-------------------------
      OPEN P_TABLE_NAME FOR 
      SELECT OWNER,TABLE_NAME,dbms_metadata.get_ddl('TABLE',TABLE_NAME) "table DDL" 
      FROM all_tables WHERE upper(OWNER) = upper(P_USER_NAME);

    END;

--------------------To EXECUTE this proc---------------------------------
var usr VARCHAR2(100);
VAR p_lst refcursor;
exec TABLE_INFO(<username>,:p_lst);
------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Comment: here is the result:
exact fetch returns more than requested number of rows
ORA-06512: at line 7
01422. 00000 -  "exact fetch returns more than requested number of rows"
*Cause:    The number specified in exact fetch is less than the rows returned.
*Action:   Rewrite the query or change number of rows requested
Procedure TABLE_INFO compiled

Comment: if we could build it as anonymous block or function will be accepted too.

Comment: Buddy this is working fine for me. No way you can get EXACT Fetch Error as here we are selecting anything INTO clause.

Comment: yes its work fine :) but where is the requirement that I talk about it?

Comment: Anonymous block or Function what is your requirement?

Comment: I have posted Function. If this helps plz accept the answer ;)

Answer (score 0):

```
Check this out. This is a function returning all the values as per requirement.

--  Obj Creation
CREATE OR REPLACE TYPE my_obj
IS
  OBJECT
  (
    TAB_NAME VARCHAR2(100),
    DDL_S    VARCHAR2(32676) );

-- Table type Creation

CREATE OR REPLACE TYPE my_tab
IS
  TABLE OF my_obj;

--Function Creation---

CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION TABLE_INFO_FUN(
  P_USER_NAME IN VARCHAR2 )
RETURN my_tab
AS
  my_otpt my_tab;
BEGIN
  -----------------------For DDL script use dbms_metadata.get_ddl-------------------------
  SELECT CAST( multiset
    (SELECT my_obj(TABLE_NAME,dbms_metadata.get_ddl('TABLE',TABLE_NAME))
    FROM all_tables
    WHERE upper(OWNER) = upper(P_USER_NAME)
    ) AS my_tab )
  INTO my_otpt
  FROM DUAL;
  RETURN my_otpt;
END;

-- Using Function to Select Data -------------
SELECT * FROM TABLE(TABLE_INFO_FUN(<USERNAME>));
```

Comment: my friend I really appreciate  your effort , please note that I am just a beginner and fresh graduated. and the requirement I think you give it more than its size,,
the requirement for that's task is create procedure or function or Anonymous  block that take the username and password (schema user name and password) to get its tables. please accept my regards and please help me

Comment: May i know what is the need for the passowrd to be passed. As passing "free" un-encrypted password over network is not at all advicable.